# Python read in excel with win32com

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

Last week I created some simple code to read in an excel where I want to save the images from:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('Excel1.xlsx')
```

However when I want to use it now I suddenly get the following error, while it was working last week:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u"Sorry, we couldn't find Excel1.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

The Excel file was not removed and is still in the same folder as the script. Previously it opened the file but now not anymore. How is this possible?

When I use `workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook` instead of `workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('Excel1.xlsx')` it works, so the problem is in opening the file I think.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880844/5585424

Comment: That is not a solution to my problem unfortunately. With that script I get the same error.

Comment: Having the same problem, did you ever find a solution? I uninstalled and reinstalled pywin32, cleared my roaming Excel cache, changed directories, re-downloaded the file. Same error

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue here was?