# How to save image from the excel file with pandas/python and give different column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file which looks below

```
Name, Image
iris, jpgimage
rose,jpgimage
```

Image column contains images of the Name column. I tried to read the file but image column coming as Nan

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('z.xlsx')
```

- Adding on more question can i save the images with name of first column?

Is there any alternate way to save the images with name of first column?

Like in folder it will save as `rose.jpg, iris.jpg`

Comment: I'm not sure if pandas has the ability to read images (like a matrix of pixel intensities or.), in order to extract and save the images, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980439/use-python-extract-images-from-excel-sheets)

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan, pandas is not necessary as python also will take care of things but how to save `save the images with name of first column?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use python extract images from Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980439/use-python-extract-images-from-excel-sheets)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+extract+image+excel

Comment: @Nons how are you saving images currently?

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan, not able to do in python, went through the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980439/use-python-extract-images-from-excel-sheets, but image is not getting saved

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan       ` if shape.Name.startswith('Picture'):` there is no line with starting with picture

Comment: @Nons after this line `if shape.Name.startswith('Picture'):`, can you write `print(i, shape.Name)` and let me know what's printed?

Comment: @Nons I think it's standard excel naming convention for pictures embedded inside it, I tried the code and it works perfectly for me. The 2 images i used for testing were read as `Picture 2` and `Picture 4`

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan, i tried the code now, only 235 images was there in the excel but i got so many small pixel images also.

Comment: @Nons the code grabs clipboard images, so it'll be able to capture the image in the exact size as pasted in the excel sheet.