# How to load an excel sheet with chart in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, charts

I have an excel file(`a.xlsx`) with sheets name `s1` and `s2` respectively. `s1` contains data. Using this data I have created a bar chart in `s2`.

Now I am trying to load the s2 sheet in python as follows:

```
pandas.read_excel("a.xlsx",sheet_name = "s2")
```

Which gives me a `ValueError: Worksheet not found`

How to get read of this?
Actually I want to save that chart in `png` format.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: pd.read_excel won't get you the image as png. [Extract images from Excel file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039535/extract-images-from-excel-file-with-python) may help you and there is a [excel2img](https://github.com/glexey/excel2img) which you may give a try as well.

Comment: @MagusO_O
`excel2img` has no option to save image in higher resolution.

1st answer of 1st link also not working. Issue in `SheetImageLoader(sheet)`