# Loading Image from excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

My excel file have several sheets, each sheets have pictures. I want my excel pictures automatically  seperate to different folder and folder name is my sheet name.

I already try two methods

1. Using zip2img: I know we can find pictures if you name your extension file name from excel to zip, and you can get pictures from "media" folder. However, all pictures will in "media" folder and can't seperate by sheet name.
2. Using openpyxl: openpyxl can let you get picutre from excel, but since my picture is not insert in excel so every time I extract my file it will return nothing.

Could anyone help me to figure our or share your experience?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `openpyxl_image_loader`? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62045318/11286032) talks about how to load an image from an excel sheet.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, every time I extract it will return nothing. It seems like another issue for me .

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? It be easier to help out.