# Extracting images/pictures from an Excelfile

Tags: python, image, graphics, xlsx

I am struggling with extracting images from an Excelfile using python. I have looked and searched everywhere and did not find anything that would work. Can anyone suggest any working methods on how to extract images from an .xlsx file using python? I would be very happy if someone has a working method.
Kind Regards

I tried enerything but nothinf seemed to work

Comment: Maybe this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040549/2836621