# python win32com focusing or open excel file

Tags: python, win32com

i am trying to focus to excel file using win32com.client.

what i want is:

(1) simply return workbook instance when a given excel file is already opened.

(2) if that excel file is not opened yet >> open the excel file and then return workbook instance.

i am struggling because i don't know the difference between the methods getactiveobject & dispatch and so on...

in many cases, an error occurs >> (-2147352567 .......

can anyone make the code that i want?

this is a part of my code

```
'''
import win32com.client
xlsApp=win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
myWB=xlsApp.Workbooks(workbook_name) 
'''
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you [fix the markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your post? It will help other's see the question more clearly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before this is how I did it

```py
import pygetwindow as gw
import pywinauto

def focus_to_window(window_title=None): 
     window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(window_title)[0] 
     if window.isActive == False: 
         try: 
             pywinauto.application.Application().connect(handle=window._hWnd).top_window().set_focus() 
         except: 
             print('No permission')
```

That function requires you to pass in a window title, it does not have to be exact name for example if you have Discord named `Discord #general` you just need to put `Discord` because no matter where you go `Discord` string will always be in there

Also the reason why it prints `No permission` because some applications requires it to run as Admin

Comment: thank you for your help, but this is not i wanted.... not just focus to window, i need to get(return) excel instance to do something with win32com

Comment: Sorry I might've misunderstood. But maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877278/python-open-excel-workbook-using-win32-com-api